# CodeIgniter model not right with where condition

Tags: codeigniter, where-clause

I have this code in my model:

```
$this->db->where('transaction_income_barcode.barcode_number', $barcode_number);
```

The value of `$barcode_number` is `000500007301000005304778`

So I compare using PHP it is the correct value:

```
if($_POST['barcode_number'] == '000500007301000005304778')
```

but somehow via the model it is not working correctly.

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't tell from that.  What's the generated query? (`$this->db->last_query()`) and what's not working?

Comment: i can't get data from database .. in database i have barcode number 000500007201000005304777 but when i create query using active record i cant get the data

Comment: What does this give you? `var_dump($this->db->last_query()); exit`

Comment: string(351) "SELECT `transaction_outcome_barcode`.*, `transaction_detail`.`nominalID`, `transaction_detail`.`nominalID` FROM (`transaction_outcome_barcode`) LEFT JOIN `transaction_detail` ON `transaction_detail`.`id` = `transaction_outcome_barcode`.`detailID` WHERE `transaction_outcome_barcode`.`transactionID` = '18' ORDER BY `transaction_detail`.`nominalID` asc" 1

Comment: Your question is about `barcode_number`, but this query has a condition for `transactionID`.  Are you `var_dump()`ing *after* you execute this query?

Comment: when i update the data in database and then the data can be search,i was test. 1. im update the data 000500007401000005304779 to M000500007401000005304779 and then data can be search and when i edit to 000500007401000005304779 the data can be search too.. but when im not updated the data cant be search

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Forget all the chatter of `var_dump()` or complicated `last_query()`, simply follow the CI process of profiling your code and add:

```
$this->output->enable_profiler(TRUE);
```

In your controller after the active call. This will show you your `FULL SQL QUERY` (actually, all queries on that page).

Cleanest way to go about it, my suspicion is that your value is being converted to a `int` and it STRIPS out the leading `000`'s

Take care of that by doing a cast:

```
$this->db->where('transaction_income_barcode.barcode_number', (string)$barcode_number );
```

*As a side note:*
Don't use `$_POST['barcode_number']` instead be safe with CI's `$this->input->post('barcode_number');`

Comment: good to hear, take a look at the codeigniter userguide, it gives you great examples!